# Django.Как вывести переменную с ajax в html

Tags: python, django

Js:

```
  <script>
    var interval
   function callAjax(){ 
   $.ajax({
  type: "GET",

  url: "../row_han_two",

  data: {
   'id_group': $("#id_group").val(),
  },
  

  cache : false,
  
  success: function(data){
     rot_message = data
     interval = setTimeout(callAjax, 1000);  
  }
}); 

  }
  callAjax()
  </script>
```

views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,Group
from django.contrib.auth import models
from create_group_handler.models import Parameters_User
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from create_group_handler.models import UserProfile
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from rot.models import Rot_model
from django.http import JsonResponse
import time
@login_required
def row_han_two(request):
    rot_message = Rot_model.objects.filter(id_chat = request.GET['id_group'])
    return HttpResponse(rot_message)
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, как вы можете отобразить переменную chat_message в html вот так:

```
    {% for object in rot_message%} 
           <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-3 block_messeage">
        <span class="span_block_messeage">{{object.name_author}} ,{{object.time_message}}</span>
                <br>
               {{object.text_message }}
      </div>
   </div> 
    {% endfor %}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста,как это можно сделать,уже неделю через поисковик не могу найти ответа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

самый простой вариант - возвращать не список объектов попадающих под фильтр, а результирующий html

я бы сделал как-то так:

создал шаблон `rot_message.html`

```
<div id="rot_message_list">
   {% for object in rot_message %} 
           <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-3 block_messeage">
        <span class="span_block_messeage">{{object.name_author}} ,{{object.time_message}}</span>
                <br>
               {{object.text_message }}
      </div>
   </div> 
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

затем во view возвращал бы html на основе этого шаблона

```
...
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import JsonResponse
...

@login_required
def row_han_two(request):
    rot_message = Rot_model.objects.filter(id_chat = request.GET['id_group'])
    return JsonResponse({"html": render_to_string("rot_message.html", {"rot_message": rot_message})}
```

и соответственно переделал бы функцию callAjax() что бы она заменяла блок `#rot_message_list` полученным html

```
function callAjax(){ 
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../row_han_two",
    data: {
        'id_group': $("#id_group").val(),
    },
    cache : false,
    success: function(data){
        rot_message = data.html;
        interval = setTimeout(callAjax, 1000);  
        $('#rot_message_list').replaceWith($(data.html));
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
```

}

Comment: Спасибо огромное,помогло)